# How to find minimum load for 5V rail of the power supply?

Tags: power-supply, resistors, atx, dummy-load

[image: power supply details]
I have 450 ATX 12V V 2.2 power supply. I am going to use this power supply as my power bench supply. But I couldn't find the minimum load that takes on 5V rail. Beacuse its pretty old PSU and no information on the internet. But I have managed to find its manufactured year. Its 2008.
I have W10R47J ceramic resistor attached to a one of 5 V rail and the ground rail. As soon as I turn on the power supply that resistor gets very hot. I can't even touch it. How to find minimum load of the 5 V rail and how to calculate resistor value that need to operate the power supply properly?

Comment: (It's entirely normal for power resistors to heat up to way beyond the boiling point of water at even half rated power.)

Comment: _"how to calculate resistor value that need"_ Ohm's law.

Comment: The minimum 5 V draw varies between power supplies, so connect something and see whether it works. We used to use an old spinning rust HDD and just plug it into one of the connectors. A 12 V lamp on the 5 V rail would also make a good load, and double as a (very dim) indicator light to let you know it's running.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard for minimum load in the ATX 12V 2.2 requirements so it's up to the individual manufacturer.

A 10% of full load is one rule of thumb, which would mean 2A => 10W on the 5V line. So 2.5Ω. You could buy a couple of chassis-mount 5Ω 10W (derated) wirewound resistors and test if both are actually required.

Yours appears to be a 0.47Ω resistor, which would like to dissipate more than 50W, so clearly excessive (and probably too much for the resistor rating- 10W looks like- so its life would be short and briefly incandescent).